# Make jsp fields readonly based on document creation

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I have a Struts 2 , spring security app. I have a requirement for which I need to make the fields in JSP read only. If the user logged in is not the creator of document then he/she should not be able to edit the document just view the information. Is there any way I can achieve this using struts and JSP ? Or I need to have a different form for read and edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really several ways to do this.

Assuming a `List<Document> documents;`, and the `Document` object having fields like `documentId`, `ownerId`, `description`, and a User object stored somewhere, and accessible through getCurrentUser() (eg. from a BaseAction extended by the other ones), you can check it inline with

```
<s:iterator value="allDocuments" var="currentDocument" status="stat">
    <s:hidden name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].documentId />

    <s:if test="%{currentUser.id.equals(#currentDocument.ownerId)}">
        <s:textfield name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].description" />
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:textfield name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].description" 
                 readonly="true" />
    </s:else>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

In case you have to perform more complicated checks, you can call an Action function while iterating the documents:

```xml
<s:iterator value="allDocuments" var="currentDocument" status="stat">
    <s:hidden name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].documentId />

    <s:if test="%{amIOwnerOfThisDocument(#currentDocument.ownerId)}">
        <s:textfield name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].description" />
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:textfield name="allDocuments[%{#stat.index}"].description" 
                 readonly="true" />
    </s:else>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

and in the Action:

```java
public boolean amIOwnerOfThisDocument(String ownerId){
    return getService().checkSomethingComplex(getCurrentUser().getId(),ownerId);
}
```

And so on.

**Important :** don't forget to replicate this kind of control server side while accepting the data received from the JSP... it's easy for a malicious user to forge a request with data that should not be modifiable by him, eg. with Firebug / Firefox console, simply removing the `readonly` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

*This is assuming that you're saving some kind of an identification for the current user on your session.*

On your form, use a ternary operator to know if it should be `readonly` or not.
Something like this:

```
<input type="text" ... ${sessionScope.userId.equals(userIdOfTheCreator)?"":"readonly"}>
```

If the current user is the same as the one who created the document, then don't add `readonly` attribute, else do otherwise.

Comment: I have field createdBy in the document which saves the Username (unique field) when user first creates the document. And I am using <s:textfield> in JSP.

Comment: then that's great, now get the username of the current user and compare it to your createdBy field. Just like above.